# Litecoin transaction sent to Bitcoin address that starts with (3)

Tags: litecoin

I have an issue where I have paid and received litecoin into my Bitcoin addres that starts with (3) I am now trying to get my coins and sell them or move to a litecoin address! Can anyone advise on what to do?

Comment: If you sent Litecoins to a Bitcoin address, they're lost.

Comment: No they're not. The owner of the private key for the Bitcoin address can (in theory) spend them.